# Accessing public static members of a templated class without instantiating the template?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have a templated class and want to access a public static variable from outside it, but I can't figure out any way to do so without instantiating the template. This code:

```
template<class T>
class TemplatedClass {
    public:
        static const int static_member = 10;
};
```

...

```
int i = TemplatedClass::static_member;
```

Produces the following error: "'template class TemplatedClass' used without template parameters."

If I instantiate the class when accessing the variable:

```
int i = TemplatedClass<int>::static_member;
```

The error goes away. I would prefer not to have to instantiate a template in a context where it doesn't really make sense with a dummy type argument just to suppress an error. If I have to, what would be the best dummy type to use? I tried <> and <void>, but neither worked.

Comment: Each instantiation is a new type, so it doesn't make sense not to provide a type.

Comment: I am afraid you have to. But you use other instantiations of the template in other places anyway, no? Using one more, of the same type as in other places, shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Another way to say is that a template on itself is strictly *not* a type. And so we cannot access static members which should be, loosely speaking, members of a type (specifically a class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be done, since specializations might override the value, i.e:

```
template<class T>
class TemplatedClass : public BaseClass
{
    static const int value = 42;
};

template<>
class TemplatedClass<StarTrek>
{
    static const int value = 47;
}
```

Thus you will get different values:

```
TemplatedClass<StarTrek>::value != TemplatedClass<void>::value
```

If the values are to be equal, I strongly suggest you add a non-template base class:

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    static const int value = 42;
};

template<class T>
class TemplatedClass : public BaseClass
{
    ...
}
```

Instantiating or explicitly a dummy type (i.e. void) might work, but you might get compile errors depending on how you use your template parameter.

```
int x = TemplatedClass<void>::value;
```

So, **please** write code which show your intentions clearly, i.e. common values for all instantiations should not be in the type-dependent template class. If you can't have that, please explain what you're trying to do in more detail.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any preferred dummy type to use for this sort of thing?

Comment: void is the universal dummy type, but you might want to make your own to document stuff properly. However, I seriously recommend that you  rethink your design.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dummy type might work for trivial classes, but not if things get more complex.

Let's imagine, that your class "continues" like this:

```
template<class T>
class TemplatedClass {
public:
    static const int static_member = 10;
    typedef typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral< T >::value >::type type;
};
```

This code tells us that T **cannot** be non-integral type.

Upd (thanks to jogojapan):
That's why in some cases you cannot use **any** type as a dummy one

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @jogojapan I'm apologise... Yes, it's not an answer, but an invitation to thinking that in some cases we can't pass **any** type as dummy type. I'll edit an answer, but if you'll tell that it's still doesn't have a sense, I'll delete it